# Creating labels on Pie Charts in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I am creating a Location Pie chart for my study area using Male and Female population in ArcGIS for Desktop.

The software creates for legend of charts but I want to create a label on chart itself. 
How do I do this in ArcMap?

[image: sample map for locational chart]

[image: the chart should have label like this on its location]

Comment: Please note that the ArcGIS Idea links in the two answers below lead to *different* ideas.

Answer (score 4):

there is an [idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bsl7&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Natural%2bResources) for this at ArcGIS Idea. So apparently it is still not possible.

> It would be great to be able to automatically label pie charts by a field e.g. with the name of the place they represent, and use Maplex or similar to tailor label placement.
>   I have made pie charts representing community values at a number of places (including parks and reserves).  The pies are then sized by the number of people nominating each special place.  I would like to label each pie chart with the place it represents.  This is especially important for huge pies representing tiny reserves!  However, given the charts are all different sizes and jittered to prevent overlap, I can only do this manually using annotation, and it is very time consuming.  Labelling the feature behind is not viable because the labels overlap some pies or are some distance away.
>   Talking with others, they suggested I use histograms charts instead.  This is not viable - with many categories of information important to my clients (which I can accommodate in pies by using different tones of colour for related categories), the histograms stretch too long obscuring the map. - See more at: http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bsl7&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Natural%2bResources#sthash.o4yIoWgo.dpuf

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that this can currently be done, but there is an **[ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000buciAAA)** which I recommend you vote for.  While there search on "pie chart" because a few others are somewhat similar.