# How to label pie charts in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, chart

How can I add to pie charts in ArcGIS (10.1) labels of the values the charts are created with?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51978/how-to-add-the-label-for-located-charts-in-arcgis/