# Is it possible to label pie/bar charts in MapInfo Pro v10.0?

Tags: labeling, mapinfo, chart

What I have in mind looks something like this...

[image]

or like this...

[image]

The idea is to get values/percentages shown next to the pie/bar chart.

If it is not possible to do it in MapInfo, is there some other GIS software that has this option?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is currently not available in MapInfo.  It's also not available in ArcGIS.  See this related [**post**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70838/how-to-label-pie-charts-in-arcgis).  The [**ArcGIS Idea**](https://c.na9.visual.force.com/apex/ideaView?id=08730000000bsl7) linked in that page also doesn't appear to have been implemented.

I've also had a look in QGIS, but have not found a way to do it.  I did find this **[feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4256)** for QGIS, but it doesn't look like it's been implemented yet either.